# Swipe Tabs with tabhost inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, swipe

I've a NavigationDrawer that shows fragments in MainActivity when a menu item is clicked.

One of these fragments is called MainFragment that uses TabHost to show tabs. The tabs are another two fragments (FragmentOne and FragmentTwo).

It's all working but I can't code the swipe functionality and effects like WhatsApp tabs. I've searched many examples/tutorials but all of them show how to do it with an activity and I'm not able to implement it with fragments. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

*Only one of my fragments need tabs.*

**MainFragment:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.podtest.R;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.fragment_main);

        Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
        arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Frag Tab1"),
                FragmentOne.class, arg1);

        Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
        arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Frag Tab2"),
                FragmentTwo.class, arg2);

        return mTabHost;

    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import com.podtest.fragments.ImportFragment;
    import com.podtest.fragments.MainFragment;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment()).commit();
        }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ImportFragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the swipe functionality you would be best off using a ViewPager paired with a TabLayout. Both are provided in the design support library.

You can see a working example here:
http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/

The above example is within an Activity, but I have used a similar so

Comment: I was trying it. I can't mind how to do, can you explain?